# Is it necessary to use a procedure or function for sequential query with persistent connection

Tags: php, database, postgresql, codeigniter

I am using PostgreSQL and PHP within the Codeigniter framework for an application.

Are there some sequential query that require an order of one insert, one update and one select?

Is it necessary to use a procedure or a function when having persistent connection with database for sequential database queries?

Comment: Hey there. I tried to clarify your question by first removing some noise and phrasing it to be more straightforward (your grammar was a little off). Keep in mind that when asking a question, it is preferable to make it very clear it *is* a question, with question marks and a clear statement. I tried my best to preserve the meaning I could understand in your question, even though I'm not sure what you mean exactly by "necessity"

Answer (score 0):

1. Persistent Connection is for keeping a 'pool' for faster use, automatic management of connection usage and other associated features, not to overlook the fact that it saves the overhead time of otherwise making a connection each time for a DB query needing execution.
2. SELECT should not need a function or procedure unless 
   a. it is depending on the preceding DML operations that you do not want to 'Dirty Read' i.e. you want the insert / update operations to go to success and then only fire the select.
   b. When you are transforming the result of SELECT heavily e.g. selecting from 3-4 tables, massaging the data in-memory , applying business rules etc. before returning the final outcome.
3. Yes, it is advisable to always encapsulate your I/U/D (DML operations) into a function or procedure WHEN you want the DB processing logic to be contained in the DB itself. i.e. you don't want your UI to contain complex DB queries , arrive at performance issues due to non-binding variables in the queries etc..
   Also, in your example, if I have got it right then , you want to do step 1-3 as insert/update and then fire a select. If this was a bundled operation, then either use BLOCK mode operation or better/easier is to encapsulate it in a function/procedure so that you get a known outcome each time irrespective of success or failure of the criteria as you are controlling it in your proc/function code.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge.It help me a lot.Thanks again.